# Why does Logging onclick event turns out to be undefined in chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, onclick, dom-events, event-delegation

```
    <ul onClick='pop()'>
    <li id="1">1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
   </ul>

    function pop(event) {
    let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
    console.log(window.event); //Valid mouseEvent
    console.log(event) // Undefined
}
```

So the question is that why does logging event results to be undefined whereas window.event has a valid value ?
Browser - chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to handle the event in an efficient way. You didn't pass any event to `pop`.

```js
function pop(event) {
  let ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
  console.log(window.event); //Valid mouseEvent
  console.log(event) // Undefined
}

document.getElementById("yourid").addEventListener('click', pop);
```

```html
<ul id="yourid">
  <li id="1">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't passed anything into `pop`, so the value of the parameter is `undefined`, as is always the case when the function expects a parameter that you provide no argument for.

```html
<ul onClick='pop()'>
<!--             ^−−−− Nothing here -->
```

Two solutions:

1. Use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, etc.). Chrome (and other browsers) will ensure that `pop` is always called with the event object.
2. Pass through the event the generated function wrapped around your code receives:

   ```
   <ul onClick='pop(event)'>
   <!--             ^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−         -->
   ```

   Note that `event` in that code snippet is **not** the global, it's the local `event` parameter of the function generated for you by the browser to wrap around the code you've put in an attribute.